# Robotium - Perform tasks before executing test cases

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I have just started learning Robotium and I have written a test case which resets recorded statistics in my app. I was wondering if there was a way I could automate the creation of statistics without having to create them myself manually each time I run the test.

Thanks

EDIT:

I've now added some random values into the database before running the first test. However this results in a NullPointerException.

This is the method I use to create some stats:

```
private void createStats() {
    Context context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    mDbAdapter = new PlayDbAdapter(context);
    mDbAdapter.updateViews(8, 5);
    mDbAdapter.updateViews(7, 3);
    mDbAdapter.updatePrompts(7, 2);
    mDbAdapter.updateCompletions(8, 1);
    mDbAdapter.close();
}
```

This method is called as I run my first test. The updateViews method is below:

```
public boolean updateViews(long rowId, int views) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_VIEWS, views);
    return mDb.update(DB_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

The NullPointer is happening at the return statement in the above method. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: How are they stored in the application? do they get placed into a database? into a shared preferences? are they just a variable in the activity? how they are stored will change how we can fake them!

Comment: Yeah they are stored in a database so I guess I could just enter some arbritary values into the database, before running the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see all your code but I am guessing you get this error because you are not opening your database properly.

If it isn't that I will need to see more code to get an idea of whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I was getting the NullPointer. I forgot to open my adapter before accessing the database. Such a silly error!